# map2() function in pipe

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I got a tibble results as below

```
> df
# A tibble: 6 x 5
terms results              R.squared        minP  maxP
<dbl> <list>                   <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl>
1    11 <tibble [6 x 9]>         0.589 0.269       0.939
2    10 <tibble [49 x 9]>        0.589 0.181       0.999
3     9 <tibble [200 x 9]>       0.589 0.0655      1.000
4     8 <tibble [527 x 9]>       0.585 0.000154    0.997
5     7 <tibble [972 x 9]>       0.565 0.0000607   0.998
6     6 <tibble [1,273 x 9]>     0.542 0.000000977 0.998
```

There are some modeling information save in the `<list> tibble` `results`, which has several columns with names like "Formula", "maxp", "R.squared" etc.

What I want to do is to find the corresponding row in `df$results` with the `maxp` equal to the `minP` of  `df`.

I can get the results by `map2_df(df$results, df$minP,function(x, y) filter(x, x$maxp==y))`

Now, I'd like pipe this step with all other previous steps, such as

`....%>% map2_df(results, minP,function(x, y) filter(x, x$maxp==y))`, the `....%>%` is the steps to generate the `df`.

Unfortunatedly, I keep getting error message `Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : object 'y' not found`.

Any suggestion?

**Updated:**

Here is a reproducible example:

```
df <- tibble(x = list(data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 5)), 
data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,4,9)), 
data.frame(a = c(3, 4, 6, 8))),
y = c(5, 4, 6))

> df 
# A tibble: 3 x 2
x                        y
<list>               <dbl>
1 <data.frame [3 x 1]>     5
2 <data.frame [5 x 1]>     4
3 <data.frame [4 x 1]>     6
```

I can run `map2_df(df$x, df$y, function(x, y) filter(x, x$a==y))`, but when I am trying `df %>% map2(x, y, function(x, y) filter(x, x$a==y))`, I got `Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : object 'y' not found`

Comment: Can you use `unnest` to get out of the list-column, then `filter` to select the right rows?  (`unnest` is going to require the list elements to be data frames with the same number of columns, if I remember right)

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: There are ways around this, but it's simplest to just change the names to differentiate the two and avoid the name clash.

Comment: Wait, in the new example, to use `x` and `y` bare, you would have to be in `mutate`. purrr functions don't take data frames as their first parameters to enable non-standard eval like dplyr; they're just normal functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fear your example may be simpler than your actual data, but it would look like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(x = list(data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 5)), 
                      data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,4,9)), 
                      data.frame(a = c(3, 4, 6, 8))),
             y = c(5, 4, 6))

df %>% 
    mutate(x = map2(x, y, ~filter(.x, a == .y))) %>% 
    unnest()
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>       y     a
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     5     5
#> 2     4     4
#> 3     6     6
```

Note that `.x` is a data frame and `.y` is a vector.