# How to make nested purrr map to extract rows based on dynamic variables instead of nested loop?

Tags: r, loops, dictionary, for-loop, purrr

I have a data frame as below:

```
## Please copy following text in your clipboard (do not copy this line)
hid  ,mid    ,aprps,astart             ,aend               ,ax      ,ay     ,exph
10001,1000101,3    ,2012-01-01 00:00:00,2012-01-01 00:00:00,475465.6,1272272,41.55607
10001,1000101,3    ,2012-01-01 00:00:00,2012-01-01 08:00:00,475465.6,1272272,41.55607
10001,1000101,4    ,2012-01-01 08:00:00,2012-01-01 08:15:00,475465.6,1272272,41.55607
10001,1000101,3    ,2012-01-01 08:15:00,2012-01-01 09:15:00,475465.6,1272272,41.55607
10001,1000101,4    ,2012-01-01 09:15:00,2012-01-01 09:30:00,475465.6,1272272,41.55607
10001,1000101,3    ,2012-01-01 09:30:00,2012-01-02 00:00:00,475465.6,1272272,41.55607
10001,1000102,3    ,2012-01-01 00:00:00,2012-01-01 00:00:00,475465.6,1272272,41.55607
10001,1000102,3    ,2012-01-01 00:00:00,2012-01-01 07:30:00,475465.6,1272272,41.55607
10001,1000102,4    ,2012-01-01 07:30:00,2012-01-01 07:50:00,475465.6,1272272,41.55607
10001,1000102,1    ,2012-01-01 07:50:00,2012-01-01 11:00:00,475465.6,1272272,41.55607
10001,1000102,4    ,2012-01-01 11:00:00,2012-01-01 11:20:00,475465.6,1272272,41.55607
10001,1000102,3    ,2012-01-01 11:20:00,2012-01-01 14:00:00,475465.6,1272272,41.55607
10001,1000102,4    ,2012-01-01 14:00:00,2012-01-01 14:20:00,475465.6,1272272,41.55607
10001,1000102,1    ,2012-01-01 14:20:00,2012-01-01 17:00:00,475465.6,1272272,41.55607
10001,1000102,4    ,2012-01-01 17:00:00,2012-01-01 17:20:00,475465.6,1272272,41.55607
10001,1000102,3    ,2012-01-01 17:20:00,2012-01-02 00:00:00,475465.6,1272272,41.55607
10001,1000103,3    ,2012-01-01 00:00:00,2012-01-01 00:00:00,475465.6,1272272,41.55607
10001,1000103,3    ,2012-01-01 00:00:00,2012-01-01 08:00:00,475465.6,1272272,41.55607
10001,1000103,4    ,2012-01-01 08:00:00,2012-01-01 12:00:00,475465.6,1272272,41.55607
10001,1000103,3    ,2012-01-01 12:00:00,2012-01-01 13:00:00,475465.6,1272272,41.55607
10001,1000103,4    ,2012-01-01 13:00:00,2012-01-01 19:00:00,475465.6,1272272,41.55607
10001,1000103,3    ,2012-01-01 19:00:00,2012-01-01 20:00:00,475465.6,1272272,41.55607
10001,1000103,4    ,2012-01-01 20:00:00,2012-01-01 23:00:00,475465.6,1272272,41.55607
10001,1000103,3    ,2012-01-01 23:00:00,2012-01-02 00:00:00,475465.6,1272272,41.55607
10001,1000104,3    ,2012-01-01 00:00:00,2012-01-01 00:00:00,475465.6,1272272,41.55607
10001,1000104,3    ,2012-01-01 00:00:00,2012-01-01 07:00:00,475465.6,1272272,41.55607
10001,1000104,4    ,2012-01-01 07:00:00,2012-01-01 07:30:00,473548.0,1279171,41.55607
10001,1000104,2    ,2012-01-01 07:30:00,2012-01-01 10:00:00,473548.0,1279171,41.55607
10001,1000104,4    ,2012-01-01 10:00:00,2012-01-01 10:30:00,475465.6,1272272,41.55607
10001,1000104,3    ,2012-01-01 10:30:00,2012-01-01 17:30:00,475465.6,1272272,41.55607
10001,1000104,4    ,2012-01-01 17:30:00,2012-01-01 17:45:00,484869.7,1270558,41.55607
10001,1000104,2    ,2012-01-01 17:45:00,2012-01-01 21:30:00,484869.7,1270558,41.55607
10001,1000104,4    ,2012-01-01 21:30:00,2012-01-01 21:45:00,475465.6,1272272,41.55607
10001,1000104,3    ,2012-01-01 21:45:00,2012-01-02 00:00:00,475465.6,1272272,41.55607
## Do not copy this line
```

You can copy above text and import as `df` using `{psych}` package:

```
install.packages("psych")
library(psych)
# Please copy above text and run following
df <- read.clipboard(header=TRUE, sep=",")
```

What I need to obtain from the `df` are:

- Extract sum of `exph` in two pairs of rows, which are extracted at `aprps==4` and previous line
- If there are multiple rows with `aprps==4`, repeat it by group of `mid`
- Store sum of `exph` and corresponded `hid` in list or data frame

To make it out, I am currently using following scripts based on two loops:

```
library(tidyverse)

calc <- function(i) {

  ## Extract records by "mid" excluding the first records
    temp <<- df %>% filter(mid==i) %>% filter(row_number()>1)
  ## Extract row number of "aprps==4"
    r.aprps <- which(temp$aprps==4)

      ## Repeat operation by two pairs of rows based on "r.aprps"
      for (j in 1:length(r.aprps)) {

        ## Extract movement
        temp2 <<- temp[c((r.aprps[j]-1):r.aprps[j]),]

        ## Other operations in actual data set (jsut put example)
        exp <- data.frame(mid=unique(temp2$mid),expsum=sum(temp2$exph))

        ## Store PPA in list
        if (lp==1 & j==1) {
            df.exp <<- exp
            } else {
            df.exp <<- rbind(df.exp,exp)
          }
      }
    }

## Set loop conditions
list.mid <- unique(df$mid)
nloop <- length(list.mid)

## Initialize df.exp
df.exp <- data.frame(matrix(vector(),0,2,
                       dimnames=list(c(),c("mid","expsum"))),
                       stringsAsFactors=F)

## Loop to store PPA in list
for (lp in 1:nloop) {
    calc(list.mid[lp])
  }
```

However, as actual data frame `df` contains around 40,000 records and actual operation contains more complicated calculations, it takes more than 30 hours. I was trying to find the way to shorten the operation and now trying to apply `map` function from `purrr` to store each operation in a nested data frame, not to replace variables every time in loop operation.

Following scripts are the ones that I am trying to build, however it cannot reach desired output.

```
    ## Store df by mid into list
    nest <- df %>% group_by(mid) %>% nest()
    ## Extract row number with "aprps==4"
    nest2 <- nest %>% mutate(row.aprps4=map(data,~which(.$aprps==4)))
    ## Obtain row numbers to extract by movement
    nest3 <- nest2 %>% mutate(row.aprps4_1=map(data,~data.frame(rm1=which(.$aprps==4)-1)),
                              row.aprps4_2=map(data,~data.frame(rm1=which(.$aprps==4))))
    ## How to extract two pairs of records based on row.aprps4_1 and row.aprps4_1 and store sum of exph?

Some trials:
# It works but cannot extract records using two variables (row.aprps4_1 and .._2)
nest3 %>% mutate(move=map2(data,row.aprps4_1,~filter(.x,seq_len(nrow(.x))%in%.y)))
# Using pmap to specify range of filtering by two variables but does not work
nest4 %>% pmap(data,row.move1,row.move2,~filter(..1,seq_len(nrow(..1))%in%..2))
# Using double map function instead of double loop but does not work
pmap(nest4$data,nest4$row.move1,nest4$row.move2,~filter(..1,seq_len(nrow(..1))%in%c(..2:..3)))
```

Do you have any suggestion to make the operation fasten?
I prefer to use `map` function to learn about it, however other alternatives are also welcomed.

I also found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48847613/purrr-map-equivalent-of-nested-for-loop) similar to this issue but could not solve the issue how to extract two rows based on dynamic variable `r.aprpr4_1` and `_2`.

===== UPDATE: ISSUE SOLVED =====

I could solve the issue by following scripts:

```
## Convert df into nested data frame by `mid`
nest <- df %>% group_by(mid) %>% nest()

## Obtain row numbers to extract aprps==4
nest2 <- nest %>% mutate(r=map(data,~which(.$aprps==4)))

## Split r and expand record
nest3 <- nest2 %>% unnest(r,.drop=FALSE)

## Extract pairs of movement
nest4 <- nest3 %>% mutate(pair=map2(data,r,~filter(.x,seq_len(nrow(.x))%in%c((.y-1):.y)))) %>% dplyr::select(mid,pair)
```

The points were:

- Need to `unnest()` to expand each records by extracted vectors from `aprps==4` (cannot apply `.x%in%.y` where `.y` has more than two length )
- `mutate` is necessary to apply `map2` (codes such as`nest3 %>% map2(a,b,~f(.x,.y...))` is not accepted)

A lot of thanks for following posts to get this solution:

[Split delimited strings in a column and insert as new rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347282/split-delimited-strings-in-a-column-and-insert-as-new-rows)

[map2() function in pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50357475/map2-function-in-pipe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mention *other alternatives are also welcomed*, consider base R. Several issues derive from your initial (non-purr) setup:

1. One of the biggest issue of original code is using `rbind` inside a loop which leads to excessive copying in memory as explained in this SO thread, [Replace rbind in for-loop with lapply? (2nd circle of hell)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26843861/replace-rbind-in-for-loop-with-lapply-2nd-circle-of-hell) and Patrick Burn's [R Internal - Circle 2: Growing Objects](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). To resolve, build a list of data frames that is appended outside of loop.
2. The repeated use of scoping assignment, `<<-`, to affect the global environment from inside a local function appears to be unneeded, especially since *temp* objects are replaced with each loop so only last iteration will maintain. Often this operator is discouraged as it becomes tough to debug since global variables are adjusted. Functions are best handled when one object is returned.
3. You initialize an empty data frame, `df.exp` before calling `calc()` but overwrite it inside the loop with `<<-`. Usually, after assigning an empty matrix or data frame, one assigns by rows inside loop but this is not done.
4. Looping through `unique()` values can be replaced with `by()` or `split()` which also avoids using `dplyr::filter()` inside function. By the way, there are [performance challenges](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38882226/1422451) of using pipes, `%>%` inside loops.
5. Rather than `for` loop, use the *apply* family to build a list of objects after iteration such as `lapply` which avoids the bookkeeping of `for` loops which needs to initialize an empty list and assign elements to it (though there is nothing wrong with doing this approach). Also, in this way you avoid use of `<<-` within function.

**Base R** *(using `by`, `lapply`, and `do.call`)*

```
calc <- function(sub) {

    ## Extract records by "mid" excluding the first records
    temp <- sub[2:nrow(temp),]

    ## Extract row number of "aprps==4"
    r.aprps <- which(temp$aprps==4)

    ## Store exp dataframes in list
    subdf_list <- lapply(1:length(r.aprps), function(j) {

        ## Extract movement by two pairs of rows based on "r.aprps"
        temp2 <- temp[c((r.aprps[j]-1):r.aprps[j]),]

        ## Other operations in actual data set (just put example)
        exp <- data.frame(mid=unique(temp2$mid), expsum=sum(temp2$exph))

        return(exp)
    })

    df.exp <- do.call(rbind, subdf_list)  
    return(df.exp)
}

## subset by mid and pass subsets to calc()
df_list <- by(df, df$mid, calc)

## append all in final object
final_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
```

Because `base::rbind.data.frame` has some [disadvantages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15673550/why-is-rbindlist-better-than-rbind), consider third-party packages as replacement of `do.call(rbind, ...)` such as `dplyr::bind_rows()` and `data.table::rbindlist()`.

```
df.exp  <- dplyr::bind_rows(subdf_list) 
...
final_df <-  dplyr::bind_rows(df_list)


df.exp  <- data.table::rbindlist(subdf_list)
...
final_df <-  data.table::rbindlist(df_list)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your alternative idea. As I would write quick-and-dirty codes for my own use, I was thinking that I need to understand R's behavior to write rational codes. Your explanaiton helps me alot to get inside the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Great! Glad to help. Yes, get a good handle on R and its object model before extending to third-party packages.